# Navigate to next page in xamarin forms on tap gesture

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have click event for label to go to next page but in xamarin forms I am not able to get proper statement to move on next page from main page. I have used following code.

```
var forgetPassword_tap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
forgetPassword_tap.Tapped += (s, e) =>
{
    // App.Current.MainPage = MyContentPage;
    App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage();
    App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page:MyContentPage());
};
forgetPasswordLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(forgetPassword_tap);
```

In the above statement I got error like "MyContentPage" is not valid argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If instance of page `MyContentPage` has already been created, this ought to do it:

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(MyContentPage);
```

If not, and `MyContentPage` is a type, not an instance:

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyContentPage());
```